# Explain Contramap

Tags: scala

Can someone explain `contramap` to me?  What would this implementation look like?  What would good examples of usage look like?

```
// contravariant functor
trait Contravariant[F[_]] {
  def contramap[A, B](f: B => A): F[A] => F[B]
}
```

Source: http://tmorris.net/posts/functors-and-things-using-scala/index.html

Answer (score 31, accepted):

If you look at the following [`Ordering.on`](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/v2.10.1/src/library/scala/math/Ordering.scala#L121) method of the standard library:

```
def on[U](f: U => T): Ordering[U]
```

You'll see that `on` transforms an `Ordering[T]` into an `Ordering[U]` while taking a function from `U` to `T`. So the method `on` witnesses the fact that `Ordering` can be seen as a `Contravariant` functor with:

```
def contramap[A, B](f: B => A) = (fa: Ordering[A]) => fa.on(f)
```

I also saw the blog post from Tony and it helped me finally makes sense of this three year old [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2197880/257449) from retronym to one of my question.

Answer (score 58):

Suppose that you have a class `Conversion[X, Y]` representing a conversion from a value of type `X` to a value of type `Y`. You can either combine it with a function `? => X` to preprocess the input or with a function `Y=>?` to postprocess the output. For instance:

```
trait Conversion[X, Y] { self =>

  def apply(x: X): Y

  def map[Z](f: Y => Z) = new Conversion[X, Z] {
    def apply(x: X): Z = f(self.apply(x))
  }

  def contramap[W](f: W => X) = new Conversion[W, Y] {
    def apply(w: W): Y = self.apply(f(w))
  }

}
```

Comment: Do you mean "from a value of type `X` to a value of type `Y`"?