# Kotlin contract with high order functions

Tags: generics, kotlin, kotlin-contracts

I have problem with Kotlin nullability and I'm wondering am I able to resolve it with contracts.
For such `Java` interface: `interface Action<T>{ void execute(T param); }` there is two extensions:

```
fun <T, R> Action<T>.map(mapper:(R)->T): Action<R> {
   return Action{ execute(mapper(it)) }
}
```

and

```
fun <T> Action<T>.ifNotNull(): Action<T> {
  return Action { if(it != null) execute(it) }
}
```

There is also a generic model with nullable data:

```
class Model<T>(val data: T?)
```

Now I have created function which take `Action` interface as argument. Case is to execute action argument only when `param != null`, so it looks like below:

```
fun <T> callback(model: Model<T>, action: Action<T>){
    action
    .map{ it.getData() } //compilation error: getData return T? when action require T
    .ifNotNull() //execute only when data!=null
    .execute(model)
}
```

So now, is there any option to use Kotlin contract to ensure compiler that `action` will not execute with null parameter?

Comment: what's wrong with Alexey's answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ModelAction` in your own answer simply provides the correct signature for `ifNotNull()`:

```
fun <T> Action<T>.ifNotNull(): Action<T?> {
    return Action { if(it != null) execute(it) }
}
```

Then you've got the order of operations wrong:

```
fun <T> callback(model: Model<T>, action: Action<T>){
    action
    .ifNotNull() // Action<T?>
    .map { model: Model<T> -> model.data } // Action<Model<T>>
    .execute(model)
}
```

Note that the compiler won't be able to infer `R` for this `map` usage. You could also write it as

```
fun <T> modelAction(action: Action<T>): Action<Model<T>> {
    return action
    .ifNotNull()
    .map { it.data }
}
```

As a side note, the argument is the "wrong way around" for `map`; such functions are more commonly called [`contramap`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15457015/explain-contramap).

Answer (score 0):

All type parameters are shipped as **nullable** by default if unbounded (in other words, they are derived from `Any?`). Easy way to fix this is just to specify non-null bound on type parameter: `<T : Any>`

Comment: You mean interface methd parameter?

Comment: `fun <T> print(obj: T) { println(obj!!) }` - here `T` is called type parameter, because for this function it is a parameter that can be specified on invocation and only accept some **type**. "The type parameter section, delimited by angle brackets (<>), follows the class name. It specifies the type parameters (also called type variables) T1, T2, ..., and Tn.": https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/types.html

Comment: I always try to avoid `!!`, it will throw NPE sooner or later. Beyond this it won't work. It's not possible to store null in nonnull reference, that's why I'm asking about `contract`

Comment: `fun callback<T : Any>(model: Model<T>, action: Action<T>)` won't work?

Comment: That's because `Model` is specified to receive nullable parameter at it's declaration site, though nullability specification can be shipped via type parameter itself (`callback<MyType?>(...)`). It will work if you'll remove a question mark near to type of `data`.

Comment: And that's why compilation error is actually a contract that `action` won't be executed with nullable parameter. If you want to retain nullability of `T` in `Model`, then null check ( https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/null-safety.html ) is the only option.

Comment: `T : Any` won't even compile :). `Model` will never be null. It's single read object. Data is nullified after first read. `Let` won't help also. There is one nullcheck already :>

Comment: Almost all of these examples do not compile (for instance, because type params declaration comes after `fun` keyword, which is in `<T, R> fun Action<T>.map(mapper:T->R)`). If you could provide valid definitions of all the elements then I could reproduce the error and probably create a null-safe implementation...

Comment: I've made fixes. Sorry for bugs.

Comment: If you also could provide the complete definition of `Action` - it would be just perfect!

Comment: Missing keywords are added, it's complete :>

Comment: Action interface has to be in java. I mentioned about this.

Comment: `Model` returns just some object typed with `T`, whereas `map` function expects a **function type** which receives object of some type `T1` and returns object of some type `T2`. Worth mentioning, also, that `Action` **does not produce anything**, then `map` function is pointless for it. I get the next error: "Type inference failed: Not enough information to infer parameter R in `fun <T, R> Action<T>.map(mapper: (R) → T): Action<R>`Please specify it explicitly.", which means that here is type issue, not nullability...

Comment: Why `fun <T : Any> callback(model: Model<T>, action: Action<T>) {
    action.execute(model.data)
}` and `class Model<T : Any>(val data: T)` does not fit you? Here nullability is excluded by upper bound of `Any` instead of default `Any?`

Comment: As I said `data` is set to null after first read. It is requirement. Action doesn't have to produce anything. `map` function just allow to execute action with diferent parameter than expected, but it still came under kotlin generic nulability. I'm looking a clear and safe way to warkaround this problem, and that is the case.

Comment: "Contract" for this situation is non-nullable type, and if you explicitly specify that argument is nullable, how it is possible to omit null checks, then? It is, also, more complicated because it is Java interface and `platform type` comes into play: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/java-interop.html#null-safety-and-platform-types .

Comment: The only thing that can be done here is just making code more declarative and concise using Kotlin features, such as `fun <T> callback(model: Model<T>, action: Action<T>) {
    model.data?.let(action::execute)
}`. Here action won't be executed unless data is not null.

Comment: It would work. But code I provided is only sample which show how mechanism works. In app `execute` function is called at low level where I can't make such nullcheck. Gues it can't be done as I would like. @Andrey Ilyunin Thanks for help :)

Comment: Did all I could...
I hope that may be someone smarter will get here and will be able to help you:)

Answer (score 0):

I have created `Action` interface implementation dedicated for this usage as below:

```
class ModelAction<T>(val action: Action<T>) : Action<T?> {
    override fun execute(param: T?) {
        param?.let {
            action.execute(it)
        }
    }
}

fun callback<T>(model: Model<T>, action: Action<T>){
    ModelAction(action)
    .map{ it.getData() } 
    .execute(model)
}
```

This idea may help somebody with similar problem, but it isn't fit my expectations and I still count on solution based on higher-order function.